# image can't handled by spring boot REST framework on external tomcat on POST method. Return 404 error

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, tomcat7, tomcat8

I am working with the following environment.
1. IDE eclipse mars(4.5.2)
2. Gradle
3. Spring boot (tomcat is embedded)
4. Angular Js with grunt.

**Problem** : I want to upload image on AWS S3. When I ran on locally with embedded tomcat with "spring bootrun" command and upload the file from bowser /Postman API call, the image uploaded fine.

But when I make war file by gradle war command and run it inside tomcat 7 or tomcat 8 and go for same task, the rest controller of spring boot framework could not find the image file.

Please help me to overcome this strange issue.

**File information** :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/profilePicture")
public class ProfileImageUploadController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private ImageStoreOnAws imageStoreOnAws;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getPictureUploadUrl(@AuthenticationPrincipal OttaAccountDetails principal, MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        System.err.println("REQUEST---------------->"+request.getContentLength());
        System.err.println("\nagain info---------------->"+request.getRequestURI());
        MultipartFile multiFile = request.getFile("profile_pic");
        System.err.println("Multipart file --------->"+multiFile);
        System.err.println("\n Content Type --------->"+request.getContentType());

        //String pictureUploadUrl = displayPictureImageStore.uploadUrl("/session/picture/" + principal.getUserId(), 10485760);
        response = imageStoreOnAws.uploadProfilePicture(principal.getUserId(), multiFile);
        return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Postman API call : http://localhost:8080/profilePicture/upload (it works fine locally. But when I ran inside tomcat with war it does not work locally)

**Gradle file (Portion of code)** :

```
apply plugin: 'war'
    war {
        baseName = 'otta-web'
        version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    bootRepackage.enabled = false;
    bootRun.enabled = true;
```

Output : The print gives the following output.

> REQUEST---------------->1818 again
>   info---------------->/profilePicture/upload Multipart file
>   --------->null Content Type --------->multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------182405819892384390851841

The exact output should be like below :

> REQUEST---------------->1818
>
> again info---------------->/profilePicture/upload Multipart file
>   --------->org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@181b1cf4
>
> Content Type --------->multipart/form-data;
>   boundary=--------------------------341504561441584510876671

Answer (score 0):

Your application class has to extend the **SpringBootServletInitializer** class and you have to override the configure method. Please follow this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) for more details

**Edit:**
If you made all the necessary configuration then one thing I could suggest is, make sure that you have given the right name to your input file. In this case it should be **profile_pic**

Comment: It is added already. Please have a look below :

 @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

Comment: Yes,  I have added right input file name. I also checked with postman client with the "profile_pic" input name. But got the same result.

Comment: It is working fine for me and I tried these steps... 1) changed the package to war in the pom.xml  2) changed the tomcat dependency to provided in the pom.xml  3) Extended SpringBootServletInitializer class in application class file and overridden the configure method  4) gave the right name to the input file